# What brand and material is this insulating sheathing?

Tags: insulation, sheathing

I'm doing some work on an external side doorway/threshold - the house was built in 1912 but had some additions and renovations in at least the '70s, maybe the '50s as well.

As I was cleaning out the area between the door and the exterior concrete steps, I found this loose piece of insulation, along with some old siding and wood scraps. They definitely weren't helping much anymore.

At first I thought it was meant to say `INSULATING SHEET`, but I think it might be `INSULATING SHEATHING`. Who knows, maybe it's `INSULATING SHEEPDOG`. I was also hoping the top text was a brand, but it looks like `TM REG US PATENT`.

I'm planning on just scrapping it and handling it as minimally as possible. I got curious, though, and tried to see if I could find anything specific about it online, with no luck.

Is this fiberboard sheathing? Are there any precautions I should use besides gloves and a basic dust mask? Is it possible to tell what brand this is?

[image: Picture of partial sheet reading INSULATING SHE]

[image: Zoomed in photo of sheet]

[image: Zoomed in photo of sheet]

Comment: Looks like "sheathing"... they used to use it like that back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't really matter what brand it is. It's fiberboard sheathing--low density in the grand scheme of fiberboard. It was probably installed in the 70s or 50s. It wasn't original. Also known as Buffalo board.

It's a respiratory irritant but isn't likely dangerous. Use a dust mask. Cut it with a circular saw or utility knife.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiberboard